# bash variable expansion for scp tab completion

Tags: bash, variables, bash-completion

I use ssh at work and recently switched to Linux on my local work machine. As a result, I now have to fully-qualify the hostname (i.e. instead of dev1 I need to use dev1.megacorpnetworkdomain.com). This gets rather annoying for scp. I already have auto-completion set up for remote paths. What I tried to do is create a variable alias for the path:

```
WORK='user@dev1.megacorpnetworkdomain.com:/home/user'
```

The problem is now scp fails to do remote completion when I do the following:

```
scp $WORK/<tab>
```

Whereas the following performs remote completion correctly:

```
scp user@dev1.megacorpnetworkdomain.com:/home/user/<tab>
```

I tried to naively work around this by using `complete`:

```
_scp_expand_vars () {
    COMPREPLY=()
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    eval cur=$cur
    COMPREPLY=( $cur )
    return 0
}
complete -F _scp_expand_vars scp
```

This now correctly expands variables for scp, but breaks the original functionality of remote directory expansion. How could I achieve both? I'm assuming the original functionality is handled by `_scp_remote_files` function based on a bit of online research?

Comment: You can set up host aliases for `scp` in the `.ssh/config` file if you want to. Does `scp` not tab complete hosts you've got in your known_hosts file by default?

Comment: It does, however, it seems like the host of interest is not in ~/.ssh/known_hosts and never fires the prompt for ssh to be added there. I just added it there manually and it started auto-completing, I guess this gets me 90% there. Also, creating an alias in .ssh/config made remote completion significantly slower for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

For one, if you regularly access hosts under megacorpnetworkdomain.com, you should put it in /etc/resolv.conf; there should be a line:

```
search megacorpnetworkdomain.com
```

Then you can use all hosts by just referencing the short hostname, i.e. dev1 in any program.

For ssh you can follow the advice of Etan Reiser, an example looks like this:

```
Host dev1
    HostName dev1.megacorpnetworkdomain.com
    User user
```

When you use ssh or scp they will offer you the choices defined there with tab completion as usual.